# Is Homebrewing on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, homebrew

I've already seen a question or two that seem to at least tangentially reference Homebrewing.

Keeping in mind that there is already a beta site on Homebrewing, how much of the topic should we allow and how much should we be prepared to migrate their direction?

Comment: I honestly don't understand why there are two separate sites.  Homebrewing is all about beer.  Just seems like it would be ideal if they were merged.  I realize not everyone who drinks beer homebrews but homebrewers all drink beer (and end up knowing a lot about it).  Homebrewing just seems like a subset category (tag) of beer to me.

Comment: @BillRawlinson See: sports.se v Fitness.se. SE doesn't launch sites unless they think they'll both be successful. It's worked so far with those two, we just need to find the clear delineations and make sure we maintain those.

Comment: Technically, the Homebew.SE is not all about beer.  It's inclusive of cider and wine.  Or it was last time I checked.

Answer (score 21):

I would say that if there is a site for Homebrewing then technical questions about brewing beer at home are off topic.  But questions about "homebrewed" beer would not be off topic.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there is going to be a set of questions that would be suitable for either site.

For example, asking how best to poor a bottle of beer without disturbing the sediment: a question that is relevant to many homebrewed beers, but would also be of interest to general beer drinkers if they encountered such a beer.

I think the site will be stronger if we keep such shared scope questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think that answering some of the questions from a Homebrewer's perspective can help those who don't better understand beer in general.